# How to inspect the function returns in Python?

Tags: python, function, return-value, inspect

This may sound like a trivial question but after some time digging in StackOverflow and other sites, I haven't found a viable solution. I am currently having a function, say, like this:

```
def get_data_points(in_para1, in_para2):
    [do something...]
    dict_return = {"data_set1": data_set1,
                   "data_set1_type": "integers"}
    return dict_return

def main():
    input_para1 = [some data]
    input_para2 = [some data]
    [call get_data_points]
```

What I am struggling is to find a way to inspect the returned dictionary of the called function (here, `get_data_points`) before calling it. The inspect module provides a method to inspect the input arguments, but I couldn't find the corresponding method to inspect the output arguments. Does Python provide such methods?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That dictionary doesn't exist before the function is called. I suspect you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not just receive the return value `return_value = get_data_points(x, y)` and then do whatever you need to do with the returned dictionary.

Comment: Good points from Tigerhawk and Markus. The thing is that, may sound stupid but please forgive a newbie, I want first inspect what could be returned before calling it. Otherwise, more memory and processing time have to be consumed.

Comment: By using inspect function to check things you are also consuming memory and processing time ;) Docstrings usually give some information about the returned values. But have to be written by humans. Maybe it helps to explain what the intended use is of your program.

Comment: @Peter Smit, thanks for pointing this out. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict_return = {"data_set1":data_set1,
                   "data_set1_type":"integers"}
```

Does not exists before the function is called, since it is created at the function call, you won't be able do to this.

Even if you did:

```
def func():
    return 1
```

`1` is also created when the function is called. This is why you can't inspect values inside a function that is not called.

Comment: Good advise. Let me ask one more stupid question here: Is this case even when the intended function is a method of a class for which an object has already been created? I am trying to understand the Pythonic way.

Comment: @Xavier Yes, you can inspect the instance of a class but never the content of the methods.